# form JavaScript function checkAnswer not loading pages

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that I've been working on for a school project and I can't figure out what's wrong with the JavaScript checkAnswer function. The form and all the buttons work, but when I hit the submit button, all that loads is a blank page. I have tried researching forms but I can't figure out where my code is wrong. Why won't it check anything?

Here is the form from my index.html file:

```
<script src="CheckForm.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="return checkAnswer(this, '1', 'Correct.html', 
'Incorrect.html');" name="quizForm" id="quizForm">

         <input type="radio" name="choice" value="1"/>
            <script>getMusician(answer1);</script><br/>

         <input type="radio" name="choice" value="2"/>
            <script>getMusician(answer2);</script><br/>

         <input type="radio" name="choice" value="3"/>
            <script>getMusician(answer3);</script><br/>

         <input type="radio" name="choice" value="4"/>
            <script>getMusician(answer4);</script><br/>

         <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
```

This is the code from my CheckForm.js file:

```
function checkAnswer(quizForm, Answer, CorrectPage, IncorrectPage)
{
  var i = 0;
  var j = null;

  for(;i<quizForm.elements.length();i++)
  {
    if(quizForm.elements[i].value.checked)
      j = quizForm.elements[i].value;
  }

  if(j === null)
  {
    windows.alert("Please make a selection.");
    return false;
  }

  if(j == Answer)
  {
    document.location.href = CorrectPage;
  }
  else
  {
    document.location.href = IncorrectPage;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: it's `checkAnswer()` not `CheckAnswer()`

Comment: What are all those `script` tags in the form for?

Comment: They are for another function that holds all the answers so that it's randomized.

Comment: your form is submitting a POST request (which is why you're receiving a blank page after submit) maybe you don't need a form if your app is static

Comment: The point of the website is to quiz users on which jazz musician is playing on a recording. Is it possible to do that with a static website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need a form for this. It looks like you are creating a static site so I would remove the form and the rest you are pretty close with. Here is a working example for you.

Also it looks like you are creating some sort of quiz site. Be aware users can use the developer console to see the correct answer (the first input to `checkAnswer()` method)- I thought it would be worth mentioning that.

```js
function checkAnswer(answer, correctPage, incorrectPage) {
  var i = 0;
  var j = null;
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('musician');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].checked)
      j = inputs[i].value;
  }

  if (j == null) {
    alert("Please make a selection.");
    return false;
  }

  if (j == answer) {
    console.log('CORRECT!')
    document.location.href = CorrectPage;
  } else {
    console.log('incorrect :(')
    document.location.href = IncorrectPage;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="inputContainer">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" class="musician" value="1" />musician 1
  <br/>

  <input type="radio" name="choice" class="musician" value="2" />musician 2
  <br/>

  <input type="radio" name="choice" class="musician" value="3" />musician 3
  <br/>

  <input type="radio" name="choice" class="musician" value="4">musician 4
  <br/>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="checkAnswer('1', 'Correct.html', 
'Incorrect.html')" value="Submit" />
```